# Are we supposed to eat fish without a knife?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, food, fish

This is literally just something I've heard--that a knife is not supposed to be used, nor put out, for the fish course (i.e. on Shabbos). I ask people wherever I go if they've heard of this. Some say no, some suggest maybe, and of course the first person who told me thought yes, so I realize there is a very good chance that this is a small-group minhag of some sort.

According to some, the suggested technique is to pick up a piece of gefilte fish with your fork, dip it into the chrein, put it on your plate and eat it with your fork (also cutting it with the side of your fork).

A very educated rabbi whom I asked suggested that the custom, if it exists, might have something to do with the mystical symbolism of fish as tzadikim.

Has anyone heard of this? Anyone know who does it, to what extent, and on what basis? Thanks!

Comment: There is a chasidic Minhag practiced by some to eat the fish barehanded. It stems from when multiple utensils were not available and they were being careful to not mix fish and meat.

Comment: @user6591 Did they also not have napkins to wipe the utensils on? (Also calling that a "Minhag" is really pushing it...)

Comment: What occurred to me is that there is a halacha of *borer*, and that applies to the prohibition of using the knife (or any method) to pick the bones out of the fish. That's one reason why gefilte fish (as we have it today) was invented. To extend this idea to today's gefilte fish seems unnecessary as gefilte fish has no bones. Perhaps, this is a left-over minhag from dealing with whole fish. Maybe they prevented putting knives on the table to prevent *borer*?

Comment: @DanF But we use the knives for chicken, which has the same problem...

Comment: @DanF What about using forks for pulling out bones?

Comment: @SAH *borer* applies to taking the bad part away from the good part. When you eat chicken, you're pulling the good (meat) out of the bad (the bone).

Comment: @DoubleAA What about it? You can't do that either.

Comment: @DanF Why is there no minhag to not use forks?

Comment: @DoubleAA I wouldn't know. I'm just assuming that fish knives are better for removing bones as well as cutting the fish itself, than forks are. As for halacha, forks would be the same problem.

Comment: Is it only a fish-related prohibition? I can imagine two things: there are those that rather not use (iron) knives on shabbat because of its association with being a tool for war. Or the general problem of using knives that are fleishig on dairy or parve foods, because more so than forks, the flavor sticks in the serrated blades maybe mixing meat and fish?

Comment: This sounds like a North America-based question.  In North America cutlery sets do not come with a fish knife.  In countries that are more formal (part of the British Commonwealth (excluding Canada) or Europe), getting a fish knife as part of a cutlery set is common.  And in those countries it is standard practice to eat with a fish knife at the Shabbat Table.

Comment: @Ask613 "This sounds like a North America-based question" - not strictly. I would say that it is a combo of that and family custom. My grandparents lived in Poland and Antwerp, for some time. After living in U.S., they're cutlery set included fish knives and these were on the table each Shabbat. I admit that they were Shabbat violators by picking the bones out of the fish using the knives. It may warrant a separate question if fish knives are *muktzah*.

Comment: @DanF - But the majority of people in North America (that I have met) have no idea what fish knives are.  Anyway, why would the fish knives be mutkzah?   In my home of origin we always used fish knives on Shabbat to eat gefilte fish and herring.  It was formal, so fish knives were always used.  A knife is not considered a specialized instrument, which is why it can be used on Shabbat whereas a slotted spoon can never be used.  If any knife can be used, then a fish knife can be used as well for an activity that is acceptable on Shabbat.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this discussion because 9 times out of 10 when I am served a fish course on Shabbos, it is gefilte fish. Isn't this standard? (I thought the very point of serving only gefilte fish Shabbos was to avoid the borer scenario.)

Comment: @SAH it's doubtful someone decided centuries ago to avoid borer on shabbos by inventing a fish called gefilta. And Judaism unanimously accepted that ruling. Across the board, litvish chasidish, polish Hungarian etc. (What else did they agree on:) Consider also that this was not a food reserved only for shabbos. In all likelihood there was a practical reason involved like monetary considerations and health concerns which affected society at large. In hindsight, someone, rightfully or not, decided that this type of fish helped avoid borer on shabbos. And behold the reason of the Minhag was born!

Comment: Update: I have persisted in asking this question of ~every talmid chochom I meet. Every one of them says, "I've heard of that, it's definitely a thing, but i don't know anything about it." Some of them add little details like the fact that some tzaddikim only ate with a spoon (or their fingers) because they didn't want to use the other, "violent" utensils. Still looking for a real answer!